# How to check whether a two timestamps are within a range

Tags: php, logic

I need to create some code which will check if two timestamps (generated by strtotime function)  are within a range of a further two timestamps.

If they are within the range it should return 0.

If they are not in the range it should find how many seconds overlap and return the result as a number.

Comment: Timestamps are just integers. Nothing fancy. So it's just math. Compare the numbers. Subtract to find the difference or overlap.

Comment: We're here to help with programming problems, but your problem is just some very very basic arithmetic and a few comparisons. You should have absolutely no trouble handling it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  function check_range($time1, $time2, $max_difference)
  {
      $overlap = abs($time1-$time2);
      if($overlap < $max_difference)
      {
         return 0;
      }
      else
      {
        return $overlap;
      }

  }
```